# Linux: Detect all writes to memory region of a process

Tags: linux, memory

In Linux, is it possible to detect/monitor all writes to the memory region of some process?

I want to be able to select a process and detect if some other process writes to the memory region of the selected process. It is not important what is being written or which other process is writing, as long as I know that some other process than the one owning the memory region is doing it.

Comment: It is not necessary or useful to write such a program.  Linux, like all modern general-purpose operating systems of which I am aware, provides process isolation, which means that one process cannot access another's memory, read or write.  Thus, there is nothing to detect.  *Shared memory* is a different question, but that cannot reasonably be attributed to a specific one of the processes among which it is shared.

Comment: Even if you suppose that process isolation might fail to protect a process's memory from other processes, through some flaw in the operating system, a user process that wanted to monitor another for such activity would also need to make use of such a flaw.

Comment: Conceivably, something like what you describe could be incorporated into the operating system kernel and exposed, say, via a device driver, but again, you would be asking the kernel to watch for events that it is designed and built to prevent, and that otherwise it can more or less reasonably assume do not occur.  But I am inclined to think that even then it would need to rely on hardware support.  I don't think such support is available on typical CPUs or memory-management units.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response John. I'm thinking of a program such as Cheat Engine on Windows. Maybe I misunderstand how memory works, but Cheat Engine is used to read and write memory of other processes (usually games) to hack things such as health in a game. My question is not specific to games, but Cheat Engine is the best example of the type of memory change I want to detect.